# Bluestack weird Images

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks

[image: Weird Image]

As you guys can see, the icons of various Apps in Android Emulator known as "***Bluestack***" are looking **weird**.

The search icon, the **Casper App** icon and the **FB icon**...look like they are copied or inverted or something like that...
do you guys have any idea how to fix this?? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in registry, somehow by searching online I found a solution
here is the link of file which you need to download and install then restart BlueStack and it will correct your images error as shown above image

**Link:**  http://www104.zippyshare.com/v/S7QxKF0h/file.html